# How can I make a downloadable .xml file?

Tags: php, xml

Here is my code:

```
public function xmlExport(){

    $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
        $track = $xml->addChild('track');
        $track->addChild('path', "تست ");
        $track->addChild('title', "Track $i - Track Title");
    }

    Header('Content-type: text/xml');
    print($xml->asXML());
}
```

When I run code above, it prints something in the current browser page. But I want to make a `.xml` file of that which is downloadable .. Is doing that possible by PHP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `Content-Disposition: attachment` header, you can force the browser to download your 'file'.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xml"');
xmlExport();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
header('Content-type: text/xml');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="text.xml"');

echo $xml_contents;
exit();
```